# How to have my custom class throw a warning when displaymath wider than \displaywidth?

Tags: warnings, documentclass-writing

I am writing a custom class which provides a multicolumn environment (via the `multicol` package). The environment sets the value of `\displaywidth` to `\columnwidth` but doesn't actually do anything when a displayed equation is wider than the column. I would like the class to throw a warning in this case. My `.cls` file contains the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\RequirePackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    \begin{multicols*}{3}
        \raggedcolumns
        \setlength\displaywidth{\columnwidth}
}{%
    \end{multicols*}
}
```

Please provide an explanation of how to use `\ClassWarning` to throw the desired error.

Comment: `\displaywidth` is set by TeX when a math display begins; setting it outside a math display has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @egreg is there another way to globally limit the width of displayed equations?

Comment: You already get an `Overfull \hbox` warning.